# I don't get to collect the value i the return

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code but I don't collect the value `i` in the return:

```
function() {
    var i;

    var a = $('div p').click(function data() {
        i = $(this).prev().prev().before($('span')).text();

        console.log(i);

    });

    return i;
}
```

Comment: well it returns to what? It is not actually running. Next when it is enabled, it will not return anything since the click fires after it runs....

Comment: To elaborate on what epascarello said, `click(...)` registers a click listener and returns immediately. It does not wait for the element to be clicked, so the statement `return i;` will run before the click hander sets the value of `i`. The code that wants the value of `i` needs to be run from the click handler, like the statement `console.log(i);`. This can be done using [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). To get more help, post details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please provide some the rest of the HTML. Like the part that contains the `div p` and the `span`

Comment: <div class="card">
  <p class="subscription-header" style="font-size: 0.9em">
    <img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" />
    <a href="url">Text1</a><br />
    <span style="position: relative; top: -5px; font-size: 0.9em">Description</span>
  </p>

  <p class="banner">
     <img src="/url" />
  </p>
  <p class="link">
    <a href="url">Text2 >></a>
  </p>

   <p class="divider"></p>

   <p class="actionlink-double">
        <a href="url">option1</a>
        <a href="url">option2</a>
  </p>
 </div>

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am working in this a lot days but I don't get it result yet. This is the HTML:

Comment: The goal would be to do click in Text2 or option1 or option2 to collect always Text1. I am working with this function because I need to recuperate this value for Google analytics and I am using Tag Manager

Comment: function (){
var i;

 var a = $('div p').click(function (callback) {
      i = $(this).prev().prev().before($('span')).text();
 
  callback(i);
    });
  
 return i;
}

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `click(...)` registers a click listener and returns immediately. It does not wait for the element to be clicked, so the statement `return i;` will run before the click hander sets the value of `i`.

The code that wants the value of `i` needs to be run from the click handler, like the statement `console.log(i);`. This can be done using [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function):

```js
function addClickListeners(callback) {
  // callback should be a function; it will be called when a link
  // is clicked and the associated text will be passed as a parameter.
  $('div p').click(function data() {
    // WARNING: .before() inserts content before an element
    // (see http://api.jquery.com/before/).
    // This is probably not what was intended!
    var i = $(this).prev().prev().before($('span')).text();
    console.log("click listener called, i:", i);
    callback(i);
  });
}

function doSomeAnalytics(i) {
  // do whatever you need to do here
  console.log("analytics function called, i:", i);
}

addClickListeners(doSomeAnalytics);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <p class="subscription-header">
    <img src="/micuentamovil/appicon/219/46" />
    <a href="#">Text1</a>
    <br />
    <span>Description</span>
  </p>
  <p class="banner">
    <img src="/url" />
  </p>
  <p class="link">
    <a href="#">Text2 >></a>
  </p>
  <p class="divider"></p>
  <p class="actionlink-double">
    <a href="#">option1</a>
    <a href="#">option2</a>
  </p>
</div>
```